# How to find meta_values to call

Tags: loop

This thing has really confused me, when writting a custom query with `wp_query` we have pass multiple arguments. But i am using woocommerce, and i found this part of query on some form, which is

```
$args = array(  
'post_type' => 'product',  
'meta_key' => '_featured',  
'meta_value' => 'yes',  
'posts_per_page' => 10
```

My question is, how to find out, the `meta_key`, do i look into database? or backend? suppose i want to find out about a product information, lets say how many grams or lets says colors of a shirt. How and where do i look for it, to pass it along with `meta_key`? Do i look into database or where? and after i get the meta_key, how do i display it in the loop, like we say `the_title()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the post edit screen you can have the »Custom Fields« meta box, looking somewhat like shown [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Usage). You might have to enable it via the [screen options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Screen#Screen_Options). This way you can see the meta data for the edited post, but underscored meta data won't be shown, because it is [hidden](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields). To make the hidden meta visible during development put this into your `functions.php`:

```
    function unprotected_meta( $protected, $meta_key ) {
        $protected = ( '-' == $meta_key[0] );
        return $protected;
    }
    add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'unprotected_meta', 10, 2 );
```

As for a function you can use to get all the post meta, there is [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom), which

> Returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page.

For getting just keys use [`get_post_custom_keys()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys) and for values there is [`get_post_custom_values()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) available.

---

**Edit:** in response to comment

If you want to query for taxonomies you should take a look into

- [WP_Query - Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

As you're talking about archives you might want to take a look at templates

- [Template Hierarchy - Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)

because you can have one for taxonomies.

Product attributes are saved by woocommerce as taxonomy, thereby prefixing the taxonomy name with `pa_`, e.g. `pa_room-size`. If you want to get the attributes for a product you could it via post meta:

```
$product_attributes_pm = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_attributes' );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_attributes_pm);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or you use the woocommerce function get_attributes():

```
global $product;
$product_attributes_wcf = $product->get_attributes();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_attributes_wcf);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or you can get the information directly from the $product object:

```
global $product;
$product_attributes_obj = maybe_unserialize( array_shift( $product->product_custom_fields['_product_attributes'] ) );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_attributes_obj);
echo '</pre>';
```

Hope that helps and gives you a little bit deeper insight on how to proceed in your case.

Comment: The custom field is different and i know how to show them, but my question is related to getting fields to fill in `meta_value => 'somename'` how do i find it, if i am using woocommerce. Like i want to create a query to display shop items, like archive-page does.Like a custom query. The actions defined in archive page doesn't work if i copy and paste them in my template. Like take a example of loop that displays all data from shop,plus if i include and want to display my attr. like http://awesomescreenshot.com/00c2418te2

Comment: I have to go for now, but one thing I have to say real quick, you know attributes are a taxonomy? They aren't post meta.

Comment: that's clear. But how i display those taxonomy as attributes. Can i reuse actions that are in archive page? I want to display the same product loop in one of my pages.

Comment: Sorry, but I've hard time getting what you want. I add an edit to my answer to hint you in right direction - or what I think is the right direction. @Nofel

Comment: When you mention this, "For getting just keys use `get_post_custom_keys()` and for values there is `get_post_custom_values()` available." How do i use it? Is using custom_meta is starting with _ in code or do i also add a prefix of pa_

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$args = array(  
'post_type' => 'product', 
'posts_per_page' => 10 
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['_featured'];
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
  }
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer explaining what it does