# Hide custom metabox value from custom fields

Tags: posts, custom-field, metabox

Before I ask the question, I tried to added _ to the custom field, but it's not working, at least with my code.

I just want to hide the value of my meta box from appearing in the custom fields. When I added _ to the code, the metabox stopped working.

Here's the code:

```
//Creating a MetaBox for Posts to enter audio Code.
add_action('add_meta_boxes','audio_meta_box');
function audio_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box('audio_box_id', 'Enter Audio ' , 'audio_box_cb','post','normal','default');
}
function audio_box_cb($post){
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_audio_box',true);

    echo '<textarea rows="1" style="width: 98%;" id="audio_box", name="audio_box">';
        echo $value;
    echo '</textarea>';
}

add_action('save_post','save_audio_box');
function save_audio_box($post_id){
    $box_data = $_POST['audio_box'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'_audio_box',$box_data, true);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you prefixed something with `_` in the code you are showing, so I guess you are showing the working code, it would be better, I think, if you show the not working code. Besides that I don't see a reasons why prefixing the post meta key `audio_box` with `_` like this `_audio_box` to make it hidden shouldn't work.

Comment: I have edited the code. I also tried it by adding underscore to `$box_data = $_POST['audio_box'];` as well.

Comment: I guess no one so far understood what you mean by "hiding metabox value"

Comment: I want to hide the value of metabox from appearing in the custom fields as a custom field.

Comment: You have some syntax errors, to begin with, the `textarea` tag has `rows` and `cols` as required attributes. Besides you have a comma in your code that shouldn't be there. Additionally I think there is a misunderstanding, because the value of the `$_POST` variable isn't (necessarily) identical with your post meta, it is determined by the name of the form field, so prefixing it won't do anything for you. Last but not least, it is likely that your are just seeing the old post meta entry, which you haven't prefixed.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or post meta entries can be hidden from the by default in Wordpress available »Cutom Fields«-Metabox by prefixing them with a underscore - `_` - as noted [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields).

As addition, if you want hidden fields to be visible during development you can do that easily - take a look at this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126945/22534) to know how.