# Generating a random number on every post and saving it in database

Tags: php

I want to generate two random numbers above every post and save them in the database so that it won't change every time we see or refresh that page.

I've decided to put this php code inside my single.php file of my theme for the random number:

```
<?php echo rand(1000, 10000); ?>
```

and put this one for random decimal number:

```
<?php echo $rand = 0.1*rand(40,49)?>
```

but they generate random numbers between specified values every time the visitor sees the page. I want to know how to generate those random numbers and store them along with other contents of the page in the database.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need/want this?

Comment: well before that tell me what do you guess/think?

Comment: I don't know, maybe some kind of additional identification, but actually I have no clue, could be, you just like the randomness of things.

Comment: it's used for generating automated random snippet ratings for old and new posts.

Comment: ok, I see, at least my curiosity is somewhat satisfied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
if( function_exists( 'get_post_random_wpse' ) )
    echo get_post_random_wpse( 
        $post_id    = get_the_ID(), 
        $meta_key   = '_post_random', 
        $meta_value = rand( 1000, 10000 ) 
    );
```

where:

```
function get_post_random_wpse( $post_id = 0, $meta_key = '_post_random', $meta_value = 0 )
{
    if( ! ( $post_id > 0 && strlen( $meta_key ) > 0 ) )
        return 0;

    if( '' === ( $post_rand = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ) ) ) 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 
                $meta_key, 
                $post_rand = $meta_value 
            );

    return $post_rand;
}
```

where we use the *post meta* to store the random value for each post.

### Update:

A comment response: It sounds like you want to store two random numbers for each post: `_post_random_int` and `_post_random_dec` where you display/store them with:

```
if( function_exists( 'get_post_random_wpse' ) )
    echo get_post_random_wpse( 
        $post_id    = get_the_ID(), 
        $meta_key   = '_post_random_int', 
        $meta_value = rand( 1000, 10000 ) 
    );
```

and

```
if( function_exists( 'get_post_random_wpse' ) )
    echo get_post_random_wpse( 
        $post_id    = get_the_ID(), 
        $meta_key   = '_post_random_dec', 
        $meta_value = 0.1 * rand( 42, 49 ) 
    );
```

but you should avoid *cowboy coding* on a live site and test this on a dev (localhost) install.

Notice that the *underscore* in the meta key, makes the custom fields unaccessible from the backend UI. If you want to be able to modify the custom fields from the backend, don't use the underscore, use e.g. `post_random` instead of `_post_random`.

Comment: Thank you. the first solution worked fine. would that cause any trouble in the future to use the first solution?

Comment: And if i want to generate and store another random number on that page and it be decimal, should i do that by just replacing 
rand( 1000, 10000 ) 
 with something like int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max ) ?

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more flexible, now you can just use the third input argument as your random value. You can also adjust the second argument to your needs, if you need to store another value.

Comment: thanks again, but before using it on my live website, please tell if it's safe to replace it with older code and explain how to use this: <?php echo $rand = 0.1*rand(40,49)?> for decimal generation along with the previous random number. it'd be the best if you edit your final answer. really appreciate that.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: That's it. thank you, it works like a charm! you mentioned that if i wanted to modify the custom fields in backend ui i have to remove the underscore. you mean modifying it with something like ACF plugin ?

Comment: Custom fields starting with an underscore are hidden from the UI, so if you want access to them always don't use an underscore for them. You can just unhide them temporarily, see my [answer, the first part](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126945/22534). @Saeedem

Comment: yes now i understand.

Comment: Noob questions: 1) would the function go in the in functions.php file? 2) Is it right that you should enqueue this script, and if so what is the appropriate hook?

Comment: yes you could add the function's definition into the `functions.php` file in the current theme's directory, but this is a php script so it's not enqueued like js or css files. @CoderScissorhands

Comment: What is the standard/best practice for adding a script like this?  Would you not normally enqueue it, and if you would, could you please tell me which hook to use? I don't understand the loading hierarchy very well yet. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to enqueue a php snippet, that's only for javascript + css files. Just paste the function's defintion into the functions.php file, on your test install and then call it in your theme where you need to display it, e.g. in the single.php as OP wanted. You could also add it as a plugin, depends on how it's used or if you don't want it to be theme related (e.g. if you switch theme). Hope it helps. @CoderScissorhands

Comment: Thank you, as I said I'm new so I didn't know if all scripts need to be enqueued or just js/css.  That helped to me to understand things better.

Comment: You're welcome Best of luck with your WP development. @CoderScissorhands